# Is it possible to create 2 DAG with the same name having differents owners?

Tags: python, airflow

Is it possible to create 2 DAG with the same name having differents owners?
let's say the dag name would be dag_example and there is 2 users (user1 and user2)
both user create a DAG with the same name , currently 2 dag with the same name are overriding one an other but if someone know an option to have 2 dags with the same name and with diffrents owner would be great.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.
Your CI/CD can check for duplicate dag_ids and prevent this case from reaching production.

In the future when Airflow will have [multi-tenancy](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=89066609) it will be possible to have same `dag_id` in different tenants you can think of it as the equivalent of Airflow to namespace concept in Kubernetes (for example)

Comment: Thank you , very clear explainations